# No elasticsearch shard is assigned to newly added node

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES cluster, I have 10 shards and 2 replica with 5 nodes. I just added a new node to the cluster and it got synced with the cluster. Status is green and according to cluster API, we now have 6 active data nodes in the cluster. But as I checked `'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards', no shard is assigned to this node. Consequently, no elastic query is directed to this newly added node. There is nothing special in the logfile of this node:

```
[2016-11-12 14:39:21,114][INFO ][node                     ] [xxx] initializing ...
[2016-11-12 14:39:22,801][INFO ][plugins                  ] [xxx] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-11-12 14:39:22,843][INFO ][env                      ] [Chak] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [531gb], net total_space [879.9gb], spins? [no], types [ext4]
[2016-11-12 14:39:22,843][INFO ][env                      ] [xxx] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-11-12 14:39:22,844][WARN ][env                      ] [xxx] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-11-12 14:39:31,375][INFO ][node                     ] [xxx] initialized
[2016-11-12 14:39:31,377][INFO ][node                     ] [xxx] starting ...
[2016-11-12 14:39:32,616][INFO ][transport                ] [xxx] publish_address {192.168.200.8:9300}, bound_addresses {192.168.200.8:9300}
[2016-11-12 14:39:32,637][INFO ][discovery                ] [xxx] divar_elastic/GwfnlWtzTDGv42bZA2PcMA
[2016-11-12 14:39:36,042][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [xxx] detected_master {xxx}{907DRgSbTv2T-dcDOwPfSw}{192.168.200.7}{192.168.200.7:9302}, added {{xxx}{TAgbh6SmShKCPEPBtUXyXw}{192.168.200.3}{192.168.200.3:9300},{xxx}{907DRgSbTv2T-dcDOwPfSw}{192.168.200.7}{192.168.200.7:9302},{xxx}{C_b3gDlpTfu1zt0RdDlckw}{192.168.200.13}{192.168.200.13:9300},{xxx}{lYOnZzFPTiuJr7JoMNfK5g}{192.168.200.4}{192.168.200.4:9300},{xxx}{BSzFHsAMRyq8cqMh22GSKg}{192.168.200.11}{192.168.200.11:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [{Nar}{907DRgSbTv2T-dcDOwPfSw}{192.168.200.7}{192.168.200.7:9302}])
[2016-11-12 14:39:36,143][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Foo] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low] to [93%]
[2016-11-12 14:39:36,143][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Foo] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high] to [97%]
[2016-11-12 14:39:37,661][INFO ][http                     ] [xxx] publish_address {192.168.200.8:9200}, bound_addresses {192.168.200.8:9200}
[2016-11-12 14:39:37,664][INFO ][node                     ] [xxx] started
```

Any special opinion about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Problem is addressed and solve here : http://superuser.com/questions/980607/elasticsearch-not-assigning-shards-to-a-new-node

Answer (score 0):

There could be several possible reasons for the same.

1. When a node leaves the cluster or joins the master node temporarily delays shard reallocation to avoid needlessly wasting resources on rebalancing shards. 
   Check your delay timeout.

   `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/<INDEX_NAME>/_settings' -d '
   {
     "settings": {
       "index.unassigned.node_left.delayed_timeout": "30s"
     }
   }`
2. You need to check if shard allocation is set to false. To enable shard reallocation again.

   `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d 
   '{ "transient": 
       { "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all" 
       }
   }'`

If all the above are good, then you need to check master logs as to why is it not giving any data to the node. In the worst case you might need to restart the cluster, you can do a rolling stop-start of one node at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch will not trigger a rebalance of the data the moment you add a new node. In fact you really wouldn't want it to, as that could saturate your network and place strain on the cluster when it needs to be focused on indexing documents and answering queries.

You can manually move shards to your new node via the _cluster/reroute API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)

Another option (and the one I tend to use for things like this) is you can apply a transient setting to your disk-based watermarks (eg https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html). If you look at `/_cat/allocation?v` and notice that your old nodes have a disk utilization of (say) 60%, you could lower the high watermark setting to something like 55%, so that the older nodes start sending their data to the newer one with no consumed disk space. If you do this, make sure to reset the transient setting after ES has moved your data.